# Design patterns for multi-threaded messaging server

Tags: design-patterns, multithreading, distributed-computing, observer-pattern

I'm designing an instant messaging server as a personal exercise to improve my understanding and application of multi-threading and design patterns in Java. I'm still designing, there's no code yet.

My goal is to have a server that should make effective use of a multi-CPU box. I'd like the server to be distributable across multiple boxes, but wonder if that's running before I can walk.

My initial thoughts are:

- `ClientConnectionManager` has `ServerSocket` object that constantly accepts client `Socket` connections.
- `ClientConnectionManager` has a thread pool that spawns a new `ClientProxy` object when a client socket connection is accepted, handing in the client `Socket` object.
- The `ClientProxy` objects represent the client app and handles sending/receiving messages across the `Socket` stream.

Is it correct that only one `ServerSocket` may bind to a Port? I take it there's no way to have a pool of objects accepting Socket connections?

I have two ideas for passing messages between `ClientProxy` objects. Either directly between `ClientProxy` objects that are "buddies" or via a central "Exchange" object, or better yet, pool of objects.

What are the Pros/Cons of the two approaches? Does the Exchange lend itself better to a distributed app?

Would the Observer and Mediator patterns, respectively, be appropriate?

Comment: take a look at http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Oriented-Software-Architecture-Volume-Patterns/dp/0471958697 and volume two. also see http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CF4QFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dre.vanderbilt.edu%2F~schmidt%2Fposa2.ppt&ei=x0c2UrO2OonIiwL9h4DADg&usg=AFQjCNGe13lUUj3O5eg-NX5EJKQn4OX5sQ&sig2=beDH5jerjacmJt6hYftWAg&bvm=bv.52164340,d.cGE&cad=rja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it correct that only one ServerSocket may bind to a Port? I take it there's no way to have a pool of objects accepting Socket connections?

Correct. Only one thing can bind to a particular port on a given network interface at a time. Whenever a connection is received, a new socket is automatically created for the client on a deferred/internally-routed port. This is how a single listener can spawn any number of client handlers without waiting for the previous one to disconnect.

> I have two ideas for passing messages between ClientProxy objects. Either directly between ClientProxy objects that are "buddies" or via a central "Exchange" object, or better yet, pool of objects.

You can have clients receive a proxy to their their buddies' message queues whenever the buddies come online. They can then directly queue messages to each other, avoiding the need of a centralized exchange. The server would keep a reference to all of its online clients and notify the interested parties of their friends' connections/disconnections via the queue.

Scaling this to fill a single box would become a matter of adding network interfaces (or using a port range on the one interface). Scaling this across multiple boxes would require server synchronization / passing queue proxies to-and-fro willy nilly.